# Why this regex doesn't match last alphanumeric character?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to figure out why some regular expression doesn't match last alphanumeric character of some given text that may or may not contain a *YouTube* URL.

The whole regular expression is `/(?:https|http):\/\/(?:www\.){0,1}(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=){0,1}(\w+)[^\s]+/mig` (it matches a youtube.com or youtu.be URL until it finds a white space).

Here's a code snippet which works as example about my issue (it shows first regular expression's match as JSON):

```js
var match = /(?:https|http):\/\/(?:www\.){0,1}(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=){0,1}(\w+)[^\s]+/mig.exec("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8C6xDjQ66wM");

document.getElementById("result").textContent = JSON.stringify(match);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

If you execute the so-called regular expression, it'll match YouTube video id, but it lacks the last character (it should match `8C6xDjQ66wM` but it matches `8C6xDjQ66w`).

Comment: Your regex can be simplified to `https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com|\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(\w+)\S+`

Comment: @Oriol Thanks! Now's when regexp madness starts! I mean, other user might arrive here and re-optimize your own regexp, and other again... hahaha Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[^\s]+` requires at least one non-space character to satisfy the expression, so it takes the `M`.  Seems like you could do `[^\s]*` or perhaps `(?:[^\s]+|$)` -- anything that doesn't require at least one additional character.

Comment: Why don't you edit your answer and you add a working snippet so other future visitors might find this Q&A to know about a possible and working YouTube URL working regexp?

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on your own regex, here is a fixed version that includes the last letter of the URL into the capture group (just moved `[^\s]+` to `(\w+[^\s]+)`):

```js
var match = /(?:https|http):\/\/(?:www\.){0,1}(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=){0,1}(\w+[^\s]+)/mig.exec("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8C6xDjQ66wM");
document.getElementById("result").textContent = JSON.stringify(match);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thank for the effort ;)